# running google api in php cron job

Tags: google-api-php-client

I am trying to run a google API (gmail) in a php cron job.

I tried creating a server key and embed it in the code using setDeveloperKey but it is giving a login error.

here is the code:

```
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';   
require_once 'Google/Service/Gmail.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($google_clientID);
$client->setClientSecret($google_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($emm_redirecturi);
$client->addScope('email');
//$client->addScope('profile');     
$client->addScope('https://mail.google.com');           
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$client->setDeveloperKey($google_key);
$client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');

$gmailService = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
```

anyone been able to crack this? I searched in the documentation but could not figure this out.

error message: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant: Invalid code.

All is good until calling the google service. (in this case Google_Service_Gmail).  All credentials are correct.

I need a solution which is permanent. not a case where one stores a token which might expire.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I stumbled upon the refresh token.

```
$client->setAccessToken($credentials);
$client->refreshToken($refresh);
```

I created a type of cookie that lasts for some years for the script to read off the refresh token. The refresh token needs to be created. For the creation of this token, I ran a similar script that I have in a browser, saw what fields Google returns, and the rest was just to replicate it. The credentials needed were access token, token type, expires in, id token, refresh token, and created. Here are the steps:

1)Visit the authUrl that it will generate

```
 $authUrl = getAuthorizationUrl("", ""); //This will create an URL that you need to visit to generate at least once (that's why you have the offline access in your code and the auto prompt)
```

2)Use the following script, and adapt it to your settings. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/credentials

3)Store the tokens or credentials that they gave you, use refresh token in your php script that needs the cronjob, and it should get authorized as long as there is a refreshtoken.

Hope it helps, If you have further questions I can try to answer them as I'm developing a similar script.